# How to hide all videos longer than 1 minute when selected from library in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, imagepicker

I'm using the image picker library to pick images and videos. I want to hide all videos longer than 1 minute from the video list that the image picker displays.

I added the maxDuration: Duration(seconds: 60) attribute but it doesn't seem to work. Please tell me what should I do.